# How to use looping in Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have tried to accomplish the same problem using two different type of solutions. In my first solution I am able to see the window after the complete `while` loop is executed i.e after the `count` value becomes 5 while in my second solution I am getting window created first and then the value of `count` is incrementing.

**My first solution :**

```
from Tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()

count =0
def counter():
  global count
  while(count<5):
      Label(root, text=count).pack()
      time.sleep(2)
      count += 1

count = counter()
root.mainloop()
```

**My second solution:**

```
from Tkinter import *

count = 0 
def counter_label(label):
  def counter():
    global count
    count += 1
    label.config(text=str(count))
    label.after(2000, counter)
  counter()

root = Tk()
label = Label(root, fg="red")
label.pack()
counter_label(label)
root.mainloop()
```

Is there any standard method of looping in `Tkinter` in which looping takes place even after the window is created?? My second solution doesn't seems to be standard and is just calling a function after a fixed amount of time.

Comment: I'm confused here ... Your 2 code snippets do very different things.  The first makes 5 labels over 10 seconds hanging your app while it does it.  The second solution seems to keep changing the label (although i'm not sure it will work since the `mainloop` hasn't started yet ...).  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @mgilson : I am trying to execute a loop & update my value of `count` and display it in the window as it changes. I have checked both the code is executing fine but first one is completely executing and displaying the final result at a once. Can you help me so that my app doesn't hangs and displays the result as the value of `count` changes

Comment: @MahasishShome: Your second solution _is the standard one_. You may not have noticed but in you first example: your GUI sleeps for 2 seconds ,i.e, _it stops responding_. Also, it is always recommended not to use `while loop` because of the same reason.

Comment: @shaktimaan : Thanks very much for your suggestion But Sbcondor has given a answer which works for me. What do you say about his answer? Which one should I follow?

Comment: @MahasishShome: If you want your GUI to be responsive at all times, then I strongly recommend your second approach or mgilson's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that maybe something like this might be what you want:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class UpdateLabel(tk.Label):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Label.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self._count = 0

  def update_text(self):
    self.config(text=str(self._count))
    self._count += 1
    self.after(2000, self.update_text)

root = tk.Tk()
label = UpdateLabel(root)
label.pack()
label.update_text()
root.mainloop()
```

This will have the label count up from 0 to infinity -- incrementing every 2 seconds.  Of course, you can always put a condition in `update` to stop counting at a certain point or whatever...

This isn't much different than your second example really ... I've just encapsulated the data in a class to make things a little nicer, but the idea is pretty much the same (having a function call itself "recursively"<sup>1</sup> via `after`.)

Generally speaking, if you want an event to fire at particular intervals, `Widget.after` is the "standard" method that you're looking for.

<sup><sup>1</sup>Note, it's not really calling itself recursively (which is good).  It's registering itself to be called again at some later point in the Tkinter event loop.</sup>

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer!!! But I wanted an answer which is pretty much same as my first solution. I have got the answer from another `SO` user **"root.update()"** is what exactly I was missing

Comment: As @Shaktimaan mentioned my second approach and your answer is more better for responsive GUI. Thanx very much for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is in the first example, time.sleep(2) does not yield control to the event loop, so all the pack() commands are queued up waiting for the event loop.
You could call **root.update()** after each visible Tk change to let the event loop catch up on the queue:

```
from Tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()

count =0
def counter():
  global count
  while(count<5):
      Label(root, text=count).pack()
      root.update() # allow window to catch up
      time.sleep(2)
      count += 1

count = counter()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks very much!!! I think I have got my answer!!! I will accept your answer if no one else gives any answer.

Comment: But even if you `root.update`, the GUI will be frozen as you sit in `time.sleep` waiting for updates (unless you start this in another thread which then increases the complexity ...)

Answer (score 0):

Your second solution will gradually consume all the memory in your system because every after every 2000 milliseconds a new call stack is created.